# uninitialized constant Gherkin::Parser::Parser (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have just added Cucumber to my Rails app via the following steps:

Adding

```
group :test do
  gem 'cucumber'
end
```

to my Gemfile.

Running `bundle install`

Followed by `rails generate cucumber:install`

When there are no features, Cucumber seems to run as expected.

But when I add a feature file and run `bundle exec cucumber` I get the following

> uninitialized constant Gherkin::Parser::Parser (NameError)
>   /Users/purinkle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@radfords/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/feature_file.rb:34:in `parse'
>   /Users/purinkle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@radfords/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:28:in`block in load'
>   /Users/purinkle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@radfords/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:26:in `each'
>   /Users/purinkle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@radfords/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:26:in`load'
>   /Users/purinkle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@radfords/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:14:in `features'
>   /Users/purinkle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@radfords/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:170:in`features'
>   /Users/purinkle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@radfords/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:46:in `run!'
>   /Users/purinkle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@radfords/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in`execute!'
>   /Users/purinkle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@radfords/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
>   /Users/purinkle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@radfords/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/cucumber:14:in`'
>   /Users/purinkle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@radfords/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
>   /Users/purinkle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@radfords/bin/cucumber:23:in`'

Comment: Try generator with Cucumber-rails https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails.  In your gemfile add `gem cucumber-rails`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have some other gem that implements `Gherkin`.

If you have `spinach` installed, for example, that will create a conflict: when `cucumber` requires `Gherkin`, it will pull from the `spinach` gem instead of from `gherkin`

`Cucumber`'s `Gherkin::Parser` is a module with a `Parser` class in it [1].

`Spinach` uses `gherkin-ruby` [2], which implements the whole thing in a different way, but using the same names [3] (poor implementation IMO).

Try uninstalling `spinach` (removing it from your `Gemfile` and a `bundle update` should be enough) or whatever you have that might be causing a name clash.

- [1] https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin/blob/master/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb#L14
- [2] https://github.com/codegram/gherkin-ruby
- [3] https://github.com/codegram/gherkin-ruby/blob/master/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb#L13

Comment: Any idea how to make them coexist, the clean or the hacky way?

Comment: Maybe you could monkey-patch spinach to manually include gherkin, but I'm not sure how that would work out...

Comment: I'm getting the gherkin error when I use crontab -e,  when I run the same command from command line, I'm fine.

No spinach for me 'parser.rb:45:in `<class:Parser>': uninitialized constant Gherkin (NameError)''